# Add function implementation of a protocol in its extension VS Struct that conforms the protocol and implements function

Tags: ios, swift, struct, protocols

which one of the two is a good practice?

I have a protocol,
1 - Struct that conforms the protocol and implements the methods defined in protocol
2 - Extension of the protocol that provides default implementation

and I am confused,
which one of the two approaches is better to use and why?

Comment: Choose the Extension of protocol if there are many cases could use default implementation. Choose to conforms the protocol if there is no common case.

Comment: I do not want to modify any functions from their default implementation, I just might be using them a couple times @YunCHEN

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Allows you to have several implementations and swap around them.

I.e. there might be some real implementer and a fake one. Default implementation it is a default behaviours, therefore without rewriting it, you will get default functionality.